# Как убрать белый фон на картинке средствами PHP?

Tags: изображения, gd, php

Есть много картинок на сайте - хочется оптимизировать объем файлов.

Я хочу сделать следующие вещи:

1. Как удалить белый фон на картинке с помощью gd библиотеки?
2. Как обрезать фото по краям изображения, чтобы не было, так сказать, лишних областей, а только рабочая область?

Comment: @oldzas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Про удаление цвета и обрезку есть здесь https://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecropauto.php

Про ресайз, который тоже очень поможет уменьшить размер файла с картинкой - здесь http://php5.ru/articles/image#size